# Why is /exenoupdates being put in the command line when I use /qn?

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer

[Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com) bootstrap passed the /qn and the EXE_CMD_LINE gets turned into this:

EXE_CMD_LINE=/exenoupdates  /exelang 0 /noprereqs  /quiet /l*v c:\test2.txt

What gives?  Is there an inverse to /exenoupdates?  It's really hampering this project.

AJ

Comment: How is "/exenoupdates" affecting your installation?

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrapper adds it in the command line after it has already checked if a new version of the MSI is available, in case a restart is triggered, to avoid making the same search again after the restart.